# How can I display the nth line from two files at the same time (with a 'while' loop in a shell script)?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I have the two files 'name.txt' and 'extensionv2.txt', and both of them are in same folder.

Both of them have the similar number of lines.

I want to get the *nth line* (variable line) from both files in the same time into named `ex1` and `nm` variables.

So I created a *while* loop.

Everything is OK, but I can't get the *nth line* from using `sed`.

How can I do this with a shell script?

Here is my .sh file:

```
m=$(wc -l name.txt)
echo "m = $m"
t5="name.txt"
j=${m//$t5/}
echo "j = $j"
k=1
while [ $j -ge $k ]
do
    echo $j
    ex1=$(sed -n "$j{p;m}" extensionv2.txt)  # Print a variable line in file
    nm=$(sed -n "$j{p;m}" name.txt)
    echo "ex1 = $ex1"
    echo "nm = $nm"
    #v=echo "'$nm.$ex1'"
    j=$(($j-1))
done
```

I tried this, but I don't know how to get it into my code...

```
input="name.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done < "$input"
```

Comment: the `join` utility in *nix may help you, if both files of your data can be sorted by a key column. You should find plenty of Q/A here searching for `[linux] [join]` (possibly add `[bash]`) . Good luck.

Comment: Better add expected output for further help

Comment: When you say "Both of them have the similar number of lines." do you truly mean "similar" (e.g. 8 and 9 could be considered similar) or do you mean "same"? What should the output be if either or both files have fewer than the target number of lines?

Comment: The first 4 lines of your script are running `wc -l name.txt` to get the number of newlines plus the file name and then removing the file name to be left with just the number of newlines. Try `wc -l < name.txt` instead to immediately just get the number of newlines and then you won't need the other 3 lines of code.

Comment: To me your question is not clear. Do you want to get *one specific* nth line from both files or *every* pair of nth lines in a loop? Do you need the data in variables or as program output? I suggest to show example input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
LineNum=2
awk -v LineNum=$LineNum 'FNR==LineNum' file1 file2
```

To keep output in a variable:

```
var=$(awk -v LineNum=$LineNum 'FNR==LineNum' file1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be looking for something like the following (untested and using GNU awk for `ENDFILE`, `nextfile` and `"/dev/stderr"`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -d $'\n' -t vals < <(
    awk -v n=7 '
        FNR == n {
            print
            nextfile
        }
        ENDFILE {
            if ( FNR < n ) {
                printf "File \"%s\" too short: %d\n", FILENAME, FNR > "/dev/stderr"
                exit 1
            }
        }
    ' 'name.txt' 'extensionv2.txt'
)
(( $? == 0 )) || exit
nm="${vals[0]}"
ex1="${vals[1]}"
```

The above will print an error message to stderr and exit with a failure status if either file has fewer lines than the target line number specified in `-v n=`.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method I could conjure up was using `nextfile` to speed things up, plus setting `FS` to `\n`, so it wouldn't waste time splitting unneeded fields.

```
mawk2 -v __='5899997' '  BEGIN  { __ += FS = ORS }
                       __ < FNR { nextfile } __ == FNR' file1 file2 …
```